# Which report type to be used to get time taken to close a case

Tags: reporting

I need to get the average time taken by each case worker to close a case in reports. I am not sure which record type is needed to be used.

I tried using Case History record type, but  each case record is repeated twice. I am thinking its because it tracks every change to status and owner.

What i actually need is to have report where i group against each case worker
show the cases against this case worker and the time taken to close each case and in the grouping have a avg time against the case worker.

something like this but without the cases repeating
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case reports have a built in field named 'Age', which gives the age of the case in hours.

Create yourself a report based on the standard report type 'Cases' and add a filter of case status = closed.

Set the report type to summary and use 'Case Owner' as the grouping.

Then create yourself a report formula as shown below:

[image]

Here's a screen shot from my dev org - the data is rubbish, which is why my ages are mostly negative :)

[image]

Note the 'Units' dropdown on the top right - this allows you to view the case age (and thus the average) in hours, minutes or days.

Comment: Oops.. How could i not see that? :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Case object create a formula field with the number data type.

`DATEVALUE(ClosedDate) -  DATEVALUE(CreatedDate )`

Then Create a Summary report with report type = Cases. Group By Owner.

Add the columns that you want along with your formula field. Click on the Formula fields header and select summarize this field. Select AVG.